# Как правильно сверстать?

Tags: html, css

Как правильно сверстать данный блок?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Раньше я верстал таблицами, сейчас попробовал Div. Сделал так.

```
<div class="navigation">

                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="menu_icon_1" width="172px">
                                <a href="#" class="menu_href">
                                    <img src="images/menu_icon_1.png"/></br>
                                    </br>
                                    <span style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;">МЕДУЧРЕЖДЕНИЯ</span><br>
                                    <span style="color:#9d9d9d; font-size:12px;">адреса, отзывы</span>

                                </a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="menu_icon_2" width="174px">
                                <a href="#" class="menu_href">
                                    <img src="images/menu_icon_2.png"/></br>
                                    </br>
                                    <span style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;">ДИАГНОСТИКА</span><br>
                                    <span style="color:#9d9d9d; font-size:12px;">лаборатории., узи, мрт</span>

                                </a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="menu_icon_3" width="138px">
                                <a href="#" class="menu_href">
                                    <img src="images/menu_icon_3.png"/></br>
                                    </br>
                                    <span style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;">АПТЕКИ</span><br>
                                    <span style="color:#9d9d9d; font-size:12px;">по районам</span>

                                </a>

                    </div>



                    <div class="menu_icon_4" width="162px">
                                <a href="#" class="menu_href">
                                    <img src="images/menu_icon_4.png"/></br>
                                    </br>
                                    <span style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;">ВРАЧИ</span><br>
                                    <span style="color:#9d9d9d; font-size:12px;">специалисты, отзывы</span>

                                </a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="menu_icon_5" width="171px">
                                <a href="#" class="menu_href">
                                    <img src="images/menu_icon_5.png"/></br>
                                    </br>
                                    <span style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;">ПРОЧИЕ УСЛУГИ</span><br>
                                    <span style="color:#9d9d9d; font-size:12px;">в медучреждениях</span>

                                </a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="menu_icon_6" width="152px">
                                <a href="#" class="menu_href">
                                    <img src="images/menu_icon_6.png"/></br>
                                    </br>
                                    <span style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;">ОТЗЫВЫ</span><br>
                                    <span style="color:#9d9d9d; font-size:12px;">обо всем и обо всех</span>

                                </a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="menu_icon_7">
                                <a href="#" class="menu_href">
                                    <img src="images/menu_icon_6.png"/></br>
                                    </br>
                                    <span style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;">ОБЪЯВЛЕНИЯ/ВОПРОСЫ</span><br>
                                    <span style="color:#9d9d9d; font-size:12px;">частные</span>

                                </a>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="menu_vipad_1">
            321321
            </div>

            </div>
```

У каждого manu_icon есть свойство float:left и заданная ширина. Не думаю что я правильно сверстал как вам кажется?

Comment: Нету такого правильно / не правильно. Вы царь и Бог, творец сия контента. Есть на сколько криво отображается и не заметно, что криво отображается. Рекомендую взять какую то либо на подобии bootstrap 3 и ускорит процесс разработки и получите сразу адаптивный дизайн.

Comment: можно вот так - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/rgz64fzz/

Comment: @ Makarenko_I_V с удовольствием изучил бы bootstrap но я использую другое фраймворк((((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стили удобнее выносить отдельно, а меню лучше делать списком.

Основа для вашего меню:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul.menu { list-style-type: none; }  
    ul.menu li { display: inline-block; float: left; margin-left: 55px; }
    ul.menu li:first-child { margin-left: 0; }
    ul.menu li a { text-decoration: none; }
    ul.menu li a span.name { color: #000; display: block; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; }
    ul.menu li a span.caption { color: #9d9d9d; display: block; font-size: 12px; text-transform: lowercase; }
    div.clear { clear: both; }
</style>

Текст до меню

<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#"/>
            <span class="name">Медучреждения</span>
            <span class="caption">адреса, отзывы</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#"/>
            <span class="name">Диагностика</span>
            <span class="caption">лаборатории, узи, мрт</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="clear"></div>

Текст после меню
```

С шириной, отступами и шрифтами поиграйте сами. :)